# Consume google map api inside recycler view

Tags: java, android, maps

I am working on a `nearyPlaces` application that helps users get nearby locations around them. I used `retrofit` library to fetch response from google api. Everything works perfectly as you can see [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benthemobileguy/a0d13b662c713a222328c9235c49f095/raw/a28705d79b55155a3064e0021d6b87c833a5ef3f/gistfile1.txt). So. I want to parse this results inside a `recyclerView` just like google maps.  The problem is that after `consuming` the api, it displays as an `object` instead of an `arrayList`.

I really need directions on this as it has given me headache for a few weeks.

**RequestInterface**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&key="+Constants.API_KEY)
    Call <NearbyPlaces.Result> getPlacesJson(@Query("type") String type, @Query("location") String location, @Query("radius") int radius);
}
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
 private void getPlacesResponse(String type) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInteface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<NearbyPlaces.Result> call = requestInteface.getPlacesJson(type, latitude + "," + longitude, proximityRadius);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<NearbyPlaces.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull  Call<NearbyPlaces.Result> call, @NonNull Response<NearbyPlaces.Result> response) {
              Log.d("error", response.toString());
             placeResultAdapter=new PlaceResultAdapter(MapActivity.this, placeResultAdapter);
//here I need to set an arrayList to my adapter but I can't because the retrofit's data comes as an object instead of arrayList.
                  //    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(placeResultAdapter);
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NearbyPlaces.Result> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", call.toString() + "  " + t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Nearby Places Class**

```
public class GetNearbyPlaces extends AsyncTask<Object, String,String> {
    private String googlePlaceData;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
   private Context mContext;
   private Bitmap bitmap;
    public GetNearbyPlaces (Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    mMap = (GoogleMap) objects[0];
        String url = (String) objects[1];
DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        try {
            googlePlaceData = downloadUrl.ReadTheURL(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlaceData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList = dataParser.parse(s);
        DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
        Log.d("nearby", nearbyPlacesList.toString());
    }
    private void DisplayNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList){
        for (int i = 0; i<nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++){
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googleNearbyPlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
            String nameOfPlace = googleNearbyPlace.get("place_name");
            String iconLink = googleNearbyPlace.get("icon");
            String vicinity = googleNearbyPlace.get("vicinity");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googleNearbyPlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googleNearbyPlace.get("lng"));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(nameOfPlace);
            //load image icon from url;
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                    .load(iconLink)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            Bitmap locator = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.locator_red);
                            Bitmap scaledLocator =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(locator, 100, 100, true);
                            Bitmap iconBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 30, 30, true);
                            Bitmap mergedImages = createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(scaledLocator, tintImage(iconBitmap, Color.WHITE));
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mergedImages));
                            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
                        }
                    });
        }

    }
    private Bitmap createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage){
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(firstImage.getWidth(), firstImage.getHeight(), firstImage.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(firstImage, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(secondImage, 35, 10, null);
        return result;
    }
    public static Bitmap tintImage(Bitmap bitmap, int color) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        Bitmap bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        return bitmapResult;
    }
}
```

**Nearby Places Adapter (Updated)**

public class PlaceResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private ArrayList placeModels;
    private Context context;

```
public PlaceResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NearbyPlaces.Result> placeModels) {
    this.placeModels=placeModels;
    this.context=context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.place_result_item,viewGroup,false);
    return new PlaceResultAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlaceResultAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.place_name.setText(placeModels.get(i).getName());
    //Picasso.get().load(placeModels.get(i).getUrl()).into(viewHolder.car_image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return placeModels.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView place_image;
    private TextView place_name,place_category;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        place_image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        place_name= itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        place_category= itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_text);
    }
}
```

}

**Model Class (Updated)**

```
public abstract class NearbyPlaces {

public class Result {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("photos")
    private List<Photos> photos;
    @SerializedName("geometry")
    private Geometry getGeometry;

    @SerializedName("icon")
    private String icon;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("vicinity")
    private String vicinity;

    public Geometry getGetGeometry() {
        return getGeometry;
    }
    public List<Photos> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(List<Photos> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }
    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }

}

public static class Photos {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("width")
    private int width;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("photo_reference")
    private String photoReference;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("html_attributions")
    private List<String> htmlAttributions;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("height")
    private int height;

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getPhotoReference() {
        return photoReference;
    }

    public void setPhotoReference(String photoReference) {
        this.photoReference = photoReference;
    }

    public List<String> getHtmlAttributions() {
        return htmlAttributions;
    }

    public void setHtmlAttributions(List<String> htmlAttributions) {
        this.htmlAttributions = htmlAttributions;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}

public static class Reviews {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("time")
    private int time;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("text")
    private String text;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("relative_time_description")
    private String relativeTimeDescription;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("rating")
    private int rating;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("profile_photo_url")
    private String profilePhotoUrl;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("language")
    private String language;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("author_url")
    private String authorUrl;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("author_name")
    private String authorName;

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getRelativeTimeDescription() {
        return relativeTimeDescription;
    }

    public void setRelativeTimeDescription(String relativeTimeDescription) {
        this.relativeTimeDescription = relativeTimeDescription;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getProfilePhotoUrl() {
        return profilePhotoUrl;
    }

    public void setProfilePhotoUrl(String profilePhotoUrl) {
        this.profilePhotoUrl = profilePhotoUrl;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getAuthorUrl() {
        return authorUrl;
    }

    public void setAuthorUrl(String authorUrl) {
        this.authorUrl = authorUrl;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }
}

public static class Geometry {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("viewport")
    private Viewport viewport;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("location")
    private Location location;

    public Viewport getViewport() {
        return viewport;
    }

    public void setViewport(Viewport viewport) {
        this.viewport = viewport;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

public static class Viewport {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("southwest")
    private Southwest southwest;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("northeast")
    private Northeast northeast;

    public Southwest getSouthwest() {
        return southwest;
    }

    public void setSouthwest(Southwest southwest) {
        this.southwest = southwest;
    }

    public Northeast getNortheast() {
        return northeast;
    }

    public void setNortheast(Northeast northeast) {
        this.northeast = northeast;
    }
}

public static class Southwest {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lng")
    private double lng;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lat")
    private double lat;

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
}

public static class Northeast {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lng")
    private double lng;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lat")
    private double lat;

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
}

public static class Location {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lng")
    private double lng;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lat")
    private double lat;

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
}

public static class AddressComponents {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("types")
    private List<String> types;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("short_name")
    private String shortName;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("long_name")
    private String longName;

    public List<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    public String getLongName() {
        return longName;
    }

    public void setLongName(String longName) {
        this.longName = longName;
    }
}
```

}
As you can see, am already retrieving the data inside `NearbyPlaces` Class which contains the `AsyncTask` class. So i think what I need to do is find out how to transfer the data from my async task to my `adapter` so I can show with `recyclerView`.

Comment: please add model classes ?

Comment: add NearbyPlaces class

Comment: I just added three classes bro. please do well to review. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create models as per your json response

Main object

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("results")
    private ArrayList<Result> list;

    public ArrayList<Result> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Array inside main object

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("geometry")
    private Geometry getGeometry;

    @SerializedName("icon")
    private String icon;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("vicinity")
    private String vicinity;

    public Geometry getGetGeometry() {
        return getGeometry;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }
}
```

Geometry object

```
public class Geometry {

   @SerializedName("location")
    private Location location;

    @SerializedName("viewport")
    private ViewPort viewPort;

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public ViewPort getViewPort() {
        return viewPort;
    }
}
```

Location object

```
public class Location {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("lng")
    private String lng;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
}
```

ViewPort model

```
public class ViewPort {

    @SerializedName("northeast")
    private NorthEast northEast;

    @SerializedName("southwest")
    private SouthWest southWest;

    public NorthEast getNorthEast() {
        return northEast;
    }

    public SouthWest getSouthWest() {
        return southWest;
    }
}
```

NorthEast model

```
public class NorthEast {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("lng")
    private String lng;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
}
```

SouthWest model

```
public class SouthWest {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("lng")
    private String lng;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
}
```

1 Create class for all these models and copy them
2 Modify your interface

```
interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&key="+Constants.API_KEY)
    Call <Response> getPlacesJson(@Query("type") String type, @Query("location") String location, @Query("radius") int radius);
}
```

3 Modify your apicall function

```
 private void getPlacesResponse(String type) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInteface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<Response> call = requestInteface.getPlacesJson(type, latitude + "," + longitude, proximityRadius);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull  Call<Response> call, @NonNull Response<Resonse> response) {
              ArrayList<Result> dataList = response.body().getList();
             placeResultAdapter=new PlaceResultAdapter(MapActivity.this, dataList);
                      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(placeResultAdapter);
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", call.toString() + "  " + t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

4 : Now you can fetch api data.

Adapter class

```
public class PlaceResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceResultAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<NearbyPlaces.Result> placeModels;
    private Context context;


    public PlaceResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NearbyPlaces.Result> placeModels) {
        this.placeModels=placeModels;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.place_result_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new PlaceResultAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlaceResultAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.place_name.setText(placeModels.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.place_category.setText(placeModels.get(i).getTypes().get(0));
String image_url = placeModels.get(i).getIcon();
        //Picasso.get().load(image_url).into(viewHolder.car_image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return placeModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView place_image;
        private TextView place_name,place_category;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            place_image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            place_name= itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            place_category= itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have done all these but my item count return zero

Comment: if you look at my nearby places class, you will discover that am already retrieving data inside async task. Is there a way I can pass this data to m adapter?

Comment: call adapter inside onResponse method

Comment: pass data to adapter inside onResponse method

Comment: because api will call in other thread that's why you get size 0

Comment: see onResponse method and change your adapter parameter

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Please can you update your answer on how to retrieve image urls for each item? I would be so grateful

Comment: just did, please. review

Comment: it retrieves the image icons instead of the featured images

Comment: sir see your json response , there is no featured images object or variable

Comment: sir please review my updated model class. I just added my photos object.  If you check my api response here (https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benthemobileguy/a0d13b662c713a222328c9235c49f095/raw/a28705d79b55155a3064e0021d6b87c833a5ef3f/gistfile1.txt), you will see how I generated it.

Comment: sir post photo class too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206252/discussion-between-bensofter-and-kam1234).

Comment: String photoReference = placeModels.get(i).getPhotos().get(0).getPhotoReference() use this in adapter to fetch photo reference